# Toolbar not showing reputation changes

Tags: support, bug

For the last few weeks I've noticed my reputation changes are not showing up in the toolbar. Last week sometime I noticed a rep increase but no +10 in the toolbar.  Visiting the reputation tab in my user page I confirmed there was a recent upvote.  At the time I chalked this up to possibly having my account open on another computer in the house and the recent inbox msg being marked read.

Today it happened again and I can confirm that my account was not open anywhere other than my office computer. Reputation tab shows a +10 @ 2019-05-27 09:15:57Z and I do in fact see the event when I click in to "Recent Achievements" history but the familiar +10 icon was never displayed.

Comment: Do other websocket related features work? Like this inbox notification, when posts get edited, new activity in  a tag page?

Comment: It only lights up when you have a net positive gain.  3 notifications ago it went -50 due to the bounty.  Same thing probably happened on Jan 25th, -40 then.  You don't earn a lot of rep so it can go silent for a while.  Not sure how far it looks back.

Comment: @rene - yes they do

Comment: @HansPassant - thanks, that makes sense.  can you please add this as an answer so I can accept it?